# Choosing a random sound Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering how to go about picking a random sound and playing it on an event in an OOP way. My original plan was have a list in my resource loader class, and have it iterate through that. My only issue is my code constantly breaks everything when I try to implement this. How would you guys go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SoundManager:
    sounds = [] # list of sound objects

    @staticmethod
    def playRandom():
        random.choice(SoundManager.sounds).play()
```

Comment: If I already declared a file path in my Resource manager could I go sounds = [ResourceLoader.filepathvariable]?

Comment: Well, if it is a single path, it's not really random right? Only one option in that case.

Comment: I mean like instead of calling the file path here like calling something like ResourceLoader.winMusic1 which holds the following code 'self.winMusic1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("Assets//OBAT.ogg")'

Comment: Can you put your music objects in a list?

Comment: I have simply done the file paths again as it means the code isn't relying on lots of other sections of my program to work which is useful.  Thankyou for your help, I must bug the guys of this place with my Newbie questions :P

Comment: I will when it lets me which is two minutes :)