# 'str' object has no attribute 'play' while making a random sound chooser

Tags: python, pygame

Me again, yesterday I asked this question - [Choosing a random sound Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865782/choosing-a-random-sound-pygame) and have hit an issue when testing my implementation.

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "F:/Source Code/Python/graphicalSlotMachine/net/Toby/GSM/Main.py", line    5, in <module>
    class Main:
  File "F:/Source Code/Python/graphicalSlotMachine/net/Toby/GSM/Main.py", line 6, in Main
    fruity = Machine.fruitMachine()
  File "F:\Source Code\Python\graphicalSlotMachine\net\Toby\GSM\Machine.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.splash()
  File "F:\Source Code\Python\graphicalSlotMachine\net\Toby\GSM\Machine.py", line 91, in splash
    self.fruitMachine()
  File "F:\Source Code\Python\graphicalSlotMachine\net\Toby\GSM\Machine.py", line 191, in fruitMachine
    ResourceLoader.SoundManager.playRandomLossSound()
  File "F:\Source Code\Python\graphicalSlotMachine\net\Toby\GSM\Util\ResourceLoader.py", line 41, in playRandomLossSound
    random.choice(ResourceLoader.SoundManager.lossSounds).play()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'play'
```

The lists are:

```
    lossSounds = ["Assets//2SAD4ME.ogg"] # list of sound objects
    winSounds = ["Assets//OBAT.ogg", "Assets//DSWYFD.ogg"]
```

The method holding the error is:

```
@staticmethod
    def playRandomLossSound():
        random.choice(ResourceLoader.SoundManager.lossSounds).play()
```

And finally my implementation of this method is:

```
            if reel1.reelMove == reel2.reelMove == reel3.reelMove == 0 and self.end == 0:
            if self.fruitlist[0][2] == self.fruitlist[1][2] == self.fruitlist[2][2]:
                self.message = "Congratulations, you have won 0/"
                ResourceLoader.SoundManager.playRandomWinSound(1)
                if self.fruitlist[0][2] == 1:
                    self.credits += 1
                if self.fruitlist[0][2] == 2:
                    self.credits += 3
                if self.fruitlist[0][2] == 3:
                    self.credits += 5
                if self.fruitlist[0][2] == 4:
                    self.credits += 10
                self.end = 1
            else:
                self.message = "You did not win this time, try again?"
                ResourceLoader.SoundManager.playRandomLossSound()
                self.end = 1
```

Thankyou for your help in advance.

Comment: No, the error message is larger than that.

Comment: Is your list a list of sound objects or file path strings?

Comment: Full traceback: is now in the main post.

Comment: What is the content of `ResourceLoader.SoundManager.lossSounds`?  Is it just a list of strings?

Comment: How are you adding sounds into the `lossSounds` list?

Comment: I have added the lists into the main post.

Comment: I am adding them through the file paths as a string.

Comment: Er OK, so why does the error surprise you? A string does not have a `play()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you're method like so, because your list contains strings:

```
@staticmethod
def playRandomLossSound():
    sound = random.choice(ResourceLoader.SoundManager.lossSounds)
    pygame.mixer.Sound(sound).play()
```